# Need a working example of a cascading drop down list written in vb.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, cascade

I Need a working example of a cascading drop down list box written in **vb.net** for my ASP.Net MVC application.  I tried converting three examples written in C# but can't seem to figure it out and I have given up.

The examples I have tried to convert are found [here](http://helios.ca/2009/05/30/aspnet-mvc-cascading-dropdownlist-with-jquery/) and [here](http://www.michaeljbaird.com/post/2009/04/13/ASPnet-MVC-and-JQuery-Cascading-Droplist.aspx).

This is my first .net application so I'm a newbie.  The biggest problem I'm having is just don't understand the java script code in the views.

Thanks,
John

Comment: I figured it out.  In my view, I didn't match up my html select id with of the necessary string in the JavaScript...JavaScript is all Greek to me.

Anyway, if anyone wants to see my solution go here...
http://cid-8f76d4da14a1b98a.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/MVC/CascadeDDLVB.zip

Answer (score 1):

Is there something specific about the jQuery that you're having trouble with?

Why do you want to convert from C# to VB?  You'll have a much easier time with the thousands of examples if you take the time to practice C# syntax.  (The differences aren't that big at your level.)

**EDIT:**

The jQuery examples listed in the links you mentioned are pretty straightforward.

1. Page contains a dropdown list of CarModels.
2. Upon changing that dropdown, onChange event is handled via jQuery.
3. jQuery uses its $.ajax method to post to another Controller method (i.e. /cars/colors/list?model=ValueOfCarModels.
4. The controller method prepares a list of CarColors, and sends it back via a JsonResult that the $.ajax method consumes in it's callback function.
5. The callback function populates then shows another dropdown by iterating over the array of CarColors.

Which step above isn't working?

Comment: Ver 1 of my project is done except for this final piece so re-writing it would be out of the question.  I feel comfortable using VB.Net so I should be able to write an application in that language.  At the risk of getting into a language war, if "the differences aren't that big" then converting examples c# examples to vb also shouldn't be that big.  I think my real problem is JQuery/JSON/AJAX/Javascript ignorance.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first link you have looks pretty nice.

Even if you dont know C# you could download the project and use Firebug to step into the Javascript.

There is so little code in the controller that I am pretty shure you can write it in VB once you debugged through the Javascript.